# angularjs applicaton multiple response to users without request

Tags: angularjs

Hi in my application when I am opening the home page in the different browser or in different machine request done by any user reflects in every user's window.
means u are being redirected to another page if any of the users clicked the different tab.
i am calling my function from controller and i have also used `.then()` for time delay problem .
Don't know where I get wrong.

```
this.getStatisticsForNDays = function(isSwitchEnabled, id, noOfDays) {
        var requestJsonUrl = null;

        requestJsonUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/nimservice/api/v1/metric/simstat?pastDays='+noOfDays+'&deviceId='+id;
        var request = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url : requestJsonUrl
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log('response data',response);
            return response.data;
        },function(error){
        });
        return request;
    };
```

please help...........

Comment: Are you using SignalR or communicating back to users in any other way?  I don't see how the code you posted, which is only performing a **GET** request, would redirect anyone anywhere.  There must be some other part of your app that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Brenden Green i am using route.js  for page navigation. so where should i look upon ?